# Блоки отображаются не в ряд, а в колонку

Tags: html, css, изображения, inline

Есть блоки с кружками, которые по идее все должны выстраиваться в ряд. Не могу понять, почему на некоторых страницах они отображаются правильно, а на некоторых вытягиваются в одну колонку как в примере? Код и стили вроде везде одинаковые, использую `inline-block` как и положено.

```css
.mad-breadcrumbs {
  margin-top: 11px;
}
.mad-breadcrumbs {
  font-size: .9em;
}
.mad-breadcrumbs > * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
span.table {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 18px;
  width: 440px;
}

.border {
border: 2px solid transparent;
display: inline-block;
border-radius: 50%;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
width: 80px; 
height: 80px;
margin: 0 14px;
}
.border:hover {
    border: 2px solid #fcc548;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.border:hover .product-category {
background-color: #fcc548;
}
.product-category {
display: block;
width: 68px;
height: 68px;
margin: 4px 0 0 4px;
text-align: center;
line-height:60px;
background-color: #979567;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
border-radius: 50%;
}
.product-category img{
 height:auto;
}
.vert-hr {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 2px;
 height: 32px;
 background-color: #fff;
 margin-top: 23px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mad-breadcrumbs">
  <span class="table">
    <span class="border">
      <a class="product-category" href="/my-account">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar-times-o"></i>
      </a>
      <div class="vert-hr"></div>
      <a class="product-category" href="/cart-2"><i class="fa fa-calendar-times-o"></i></a>      <div class="vert-hr"></div>
      <a class="product-category" href="/checkout">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar-times-o"></i>
      </a>
    </span> 
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

У `.border` нужно убрать ширину в `80px`, а у `.product-category` поставить `inline-block`.

```css
html, body{margin:0; padding:0;}
body{font-family:Arial, Tahoma, Verdana; font-size:14px; color: black; background:white;}
img{border:0;}
:focus{outline:none;}
.clear{clear:both;}

.mad-breadcrumbs {
  margin-top: 11px;
}
.mad-breadcrumbs {
  font-size: .9em;
}
span.table {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 18px;
  width: 440px;
}
.mad-breadcrumbs > * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.border {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  width: auto;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 0 14px;
}
.product-category {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 68px;
  height: 68px;
  margin: 4px 0 0 4px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-color: #979567;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.vert-hr {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 23px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mad-breadcrumbs">
  <span class="table">
    <span class="border">
      <a class="product-category" href="/my-account">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar-times-o"></i>
      </a>
      <div class="vert-hr"></div>
      <a class="product-category" href="/cart-2"><i class="fa fa-calendar-times-o"></i></a>      <div class="vert-hr"></div>
      <a class="product-category" href="/checkout">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar-times-o"></i>
      </a>
    </span> 
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Peter Olson спасибо, но задача еще усложняется эффектами ховера для которых и нужна была ширина

Comment: @Вася Наверно Вы хотите это сказать не мне, а Дмитрию. Я только редактировал ответ.

Comment: @Peter Olson да, сорри - сразу на вас посмотрел

Answer (score -2):

решил загадку - нужно было вокруг каждой ссылки бордер поставить

```css
    .mad-breadcrumbs {

      margin-top: 11px;

    }

    .mad-breadcrumbs {

      font-size: .9em;

    }

    .mad-breadcrumbs > * {

      display: inline-block;

      vertical-align: middle;

    }

    span.table {

      display: block;

      margin: 0 auto 18px;

      width: 440px;

    }

    .border {

      border: 2px solid transparent;

      display: inline-block;

      border-radius: 50%;

      -moz-border-radius: 50%;

      -webkit-border-radius: 50%;

      width: 80px;

      height: 80px;

      margin: 0 14px;

    }

    .border:hover {

      border: 2px solid #fcc548;

      background-color: transparent;

    }

    .border:hover .product-category {

      background-color: #fcc548;

    }

    .product-category {

      display: block;

      width: 68px;

      height: 68px;

      margin: 4px 0 0 4px;

      text-align: center;

      line-height: 60px;

      background-color: #979567;

      -webkit-border-radius: 50%;

      -moz-border-radius: 50%;

      border-radius: 50%;

    }

    .product-category img {

      height: auto;

    }

    .vert-hr {

      display: inline-block;

      width: 2px;

      height: 32px;

      background-color: #fff;

      margin-top: 23px;

    }
```

```html
<div class="mad-breadcrumbs">
  <span class="table">
          <span class="border">
          <a class="product-category" href="/my-account">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar-times-o"></i>
          </a>
          <div class="vert-hr"></div>
          </span>
          <span class="border">
          <a class="product-category" href="/cart-2"><i class="fa fa-calendar-times-o"></i></a>      <div class="vert-hr"></div>
          </span>
          <span class="border">
          <a class="product-category" href="/checkout">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar-times-o"></i>
          </a>
        </span> 
  </span>
</div>
```